# How to use braced integer list initialization for constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying but unable to create a constructor for my class that takes in integer arguments (which may change to some custom data type later) through braced list initialization like the classic old `int a[]{0,1,2}`. Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class class_a {
    private:
        int ptr;
    public:
        class_a() {};
        template<typename ... Args>
        class_a(Args&& ... args) : ptr((args)...) {}
};

int main()
{
    class_a c1{0}; //works
    //class_a c2[]{0,1,2}; //doesnt works
}
```

I want an output where the variable `ptr` can be initialized as the array of integers `{0,1,2}` (again, just for now - it may change to any complex data type later)

Comment: What do you mean by `int a{0,1,2}`? What do you think that does, or what do you want it to do?

Comment: You are trying to initialize a single int with 3 values: `ptr(0, 1, 2)` - which is invalid.

Comment: Did you want `int ptr` to be a pointer like `int* ptr`? Please avoid the use of pointers, especially raw pointers.

Comment: The classic old `int a{0,1,2};` is generating **error: excess elements in scalar initializer**.

Comment: Do you want one `class_a` with three values inside, or three `class_a` instances? By writing `class_a c2[]` you are getting an array of `class_a` objects.

Comment: The code in the question changed quite a bit since I answered (`class_a c2{0,1,2};` is quite different from `class_a c2[]{0,1,2};`). The new code in the question that you claim not to work, [work's just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/4GEzh65x8)

Comment: I want three values inside (not three instances of class_a) @Ben Voigt;

Comment: Does this mean ptr is now an array of the three integers? I want ptr to be an array. How to do that? @TedLyngmo

Comment: @rupsagar Your original, `class_a c2{0,1,2};`, tried to create one instance of `class_a`, not three instances of `class_a`, and that's what my answer answers. `ptr`  becomes a `std::vector<int>` (which is array-like).

Comment: @rupsagar  I also added a version in which `ptr` is a true array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the class is not a class template (or something saying how many elements there should be in the "ptr" variable) I'm assuming that what you need is really a `std::vector<int>`, which could be initialized the way you want:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class class_a {
private:
    std::vector<int> ptr;

public:
    class_a() = default;

    template <typename... Args>
    class_a(Args&&... args) : ptr{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
    // with perfect forwarding in case you change to a user-defined type later
};
```

```cpp
int main() {
    class_a c1{0};        // works
    class_a c2{0, 1, 2};  // now works
}
```

---

If you really want `ptr` to be an array, you need to make `class_a` a class template:

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
class class_a {
private:
    int ptr[N];            // now an array

public:
    class_a() = default;

    template <typename... Args>
    class_a(Args&&... args) : ptr{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
};

// deduction guide
template<class... Args> class_a(Args&&...) -> class_a<sizeof...(Args)>;
```

But note that `class_a<N>`s with different `N`s are now different types unlike if you use a `std::vector<int>` as a member variable.

Comment: Your second solution is great; I didn't know about this use of class template. Just wanted to clarify few things:
1. if I want to define the pointer type of ptr as a template also, so that I can use it do define class_a a1 = {0,1,2} as well as class_a a2 = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0}...how do I do that?
2. do you see any potential down pit of using this type of class to define matrices like class_a mat = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}}? how do i implement that as well?

Comment: If you want `ptr` to be a pointer, not an array, I suggest hiding the pointer in a smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`  ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/1co6Gazbb)) - but that means that you need to keep track of the size of the data in a separate variable (which a `vector<int>` does for you automatically). If `class_a` is itself a class template, as in my second example, `c1` and `c2` are different types so assignment and comparions etc. doesn't come naturally. You'll have to do a lot of work if you want two different `class_a<N>` types to be used together.